# Which solvers provide an IIS feature?

Tags: constraint, solver, irreducible-infeasible-subset

I am well aware that *commercial* solvers CPLEX and GUROBI provide an IIS (irreducible infeasible set) feature. @batwing mentions FICO Xpress in the comment section as well, and @RobPratt mentions SAS.

On the side of *open source* solvers, I believe CBC does not.

Do **SCIP** and/or **HiGHS** have the IIS feature ?

Comment: I know that FICO Xpress provides .

Comment: I am not sure if SCIP adds such a feature. In [this](http://listserv.zib.de/pipermail/scip/2015-December/002613.html) link, they mentioned there is No. Also, recently I tried to do some modifications on the SCIP parameters to solve my problem, and the only parameter I saw was `maxsepanonviolated`: (maximal number of separated non-violated IISs, before separation is stopped). But, I am not sure if it can print the IIS as CPLEX and Gurobi do.

Comment: SAS has an IIS option.