# How to cmpute IIS using the Or-Tools solver?

Tags: or-tools, irreducible-infeasible-subset

I'm trying to solve a MIP using Google Or-Tools, but it's showing that the model is ***infeasible***. I'd like to know if there is a convenient way to analyze which constraint or variable bounds are causing the infeasibility of the model. I want to use the built-in methods of Or-Tools only, without using any third-party packages.

> presolving:
>
> presolving (1 rounds: 1 fast, 0 medium, 0 exhaustive):
>
> 11 deleted vars, 8 deleted constraints, 0 added constraints, 6
> tightened bounds, 0 added holes, 1 changed sides, 0 changed
> coefficients
>
> 0 implications, 0 cliques
>
> presolving detected infeasibility
>
> Presolving Time: 0.00
>
> SCIP Status        : problem is solved [infeasible]
>
> Solving Time (sec) : 0.00
>
> Solving Nodes      : 0
>
> Primal Bound       : +1.00000000000000e+20 (0 solutions)
>
> Dual Bound         : +1.00000000000000e+20
>
> Gap                : 0.00 %

Comment: You are using the SCIP solver. Does it have an IIS feature ? https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/11008/which-solvers-provide-an-iis-feature